# SAP UI5: error in binding DetailPage

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have the following code in my masterPage:

```
 onInit: function () {
        var me = this;
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "RESTAPI",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response, status, xhr) {
                debugger;
                var oView = me.getView();
                var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
                oModel.setData(response);
                oView.setModel(oModel);
            }
        });
        me.mBindingOptions = {};
        me.oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);  
        me.oRouter.getTarget("listainvestimento").attachDisplay(
              jQuery.proxy(me.handleRouteMatched, me));
    },

_onListItemPress: function (oEvent) {

        var context = oEvent.getParameter("listItem").getBindingContext().getPath().substr(1).split("/")[1]
        //context="0" (position in my array model)
        var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        oRouter.navTo("detalheinvestimento", {
            ctx: context
        }, false);

    }
```

And in my DetailPage:

```
onInit: function () {
        this.oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        this.oRouter.getTarget("detalheinvestimento").attachDisplay(jQuery.proxy(this.handleRouteMatched, this));
},
 handleRouteMatched: function (oEvent) {
        this.getView().bindElement({
            path: "/" + oEvent.getParameter("arguments").ctx
        });
    }
```

Manifest.json

```
 {
      "pattern": "listainvestimento/detalheinvestimento/{ctx}",
      "name": "detalheinvestimento",
      "target": [ "listainvestimento", "detalheinvestimento" ]
    },
```

For more information, I've created prototype screens in Build.me and I'm linking to my actual server data now.

Binding in master occurs successfully, but in non-detail.

I do not know where the error is, the model is being set in the master but when it arrives in the detail it does not link.

The fields names for the binding are correct!

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your json model only exists in the master page because you are creating it on the controller onInit method. It will not be automatically available in the detail page/controller. You should define your model in the manifest.json so that it will be available in all your your application component, including all the views. Check this link for information on how to do it in the manifest.

https://blogs.sap.com/2016/10/11/sapui5-load-local-json-model-directly-manifest.json/

2. The json model can take an URL for a rest API as a parameter, you dont need to do jquery.ajax call and handle the success case.

Comment: Perfect, but as I'm inactive in UI5, I do not understand how to set several different models on the manifest.json.
Example, I have several tiles (users, contracts, investments), each with a different endpoint in my api, how would I load several models in maniffest.json?
Another question is how would I pass parameter on my calls in the request body?
Could you give me an example?